# How do I trigger caps lock without caps lock key available?

Tags: macos, keyboard

My old macbook lost its ctrl key, so I had to remap the caps lock key to ctrl. I have a scenario where I need the caps lock on for a while - is there a way to trigger a caps lock without using the caps lock key?

I could reset the caps lock, use it, and then remap it back to ctrl, but I am hoping I don't have to do that. I also tried the on screen keyboard viewer, but that does not have a caps lock.

I am on OS X 10.10.5 and my macbook has an intel processor.

Comment: Can't you just map some other key to caps lock via system prefs/keyboard/modifier keys?

Comment: I suppose I could, but I would prefer not to. I wondered if there is a way to trigger the action without using the caps lock key (through some tool, script or otherwise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert the key mapping Caps Lock -> Ctrl. Install [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). Depending on your handedness remap alt_L (or opt_L) to ctrl and use alt_R (or opt_R) as your common alt key.

Remapping in the Karabiner context using the first example below means:
if you enable the radio button for "Option_L to Control_L" the **left** Option key will act as the **left** (and only on most portable Macs) Control key if hit and lose its original Option key function. The **right** Option key won't lose its function and still works as a normal Option key.

[image]

or remap cmd_R to ctrl:

[image]

If you don't like the remapping of alt/cmd/ctrl/R/L there are plenty of other possible remappings to emulate the CapsLock key. Just enter CapsLock in the search field and choose your preferred remapping:

[image]

You may even define your own key mappings (e.g <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to enable CapsLock and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to release it again. These shortcuts mustn't be in use by the system or apps)

*(The screenshots are taken running Lion. Since Karabiner doesn't run in Lion I'm using its predecessor KeyRemap4MacBook. The predefined modifications should be the same)*

Comment: I would prefer not having to remap other keys - is there a way to trigger the caps lock from terminal, a script or using some tool?

Comment: @Anand With Karabiner you can map almost any key or key-combination to any other key or key-combination. One predefined set to emulate Caps Lock is Shift_L+Shift_R to enable Caps Lock and Shift_R to release Caps Lock.

Comment: OK, that is cool. I misunderstood earlier. This should work for me.

Comment: @Anand Good! I made my first two proposal because most users don't use the right/left command/option keys depending on right/left-handedness. Karabiner may remap only the right command/opt key (without breaking the left command/option key!) to any other key. Since the CapsLock key really is a special key I would leave it as that and remap your broken ctrl key to the right command key...

Answer (score 0):

Check Modifier Keys in Keyboard preferences.

Make sure Caps Lock is set to the correct key, it should then appear on your virtual keyboard:

[image]
[image]

When clicked it activates Caps Lock and make all the letters capital on they virtual keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but this does not work if the caps lock is mapped to another key, as in my case :-(